# Get value of function returned by other function in one construction in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, arguments

I have a function that returns class, for example:

```
xgrid = [1,2,3]
vals = [4,3,6]
f = @(k)griddedInterpolant(xgrid*k, vals)
```

Then I can get class member, which is interpolant in this case. Then I can use interpolant to get value at every point.

```
inter = f(3) % for example
inter(100) % returns value at point 100.
```

Is there a way, I can do this in one construction? For example:

```
f(3)(100) % will return me value of interpolant
```

Comment: No this isn't possible.  You are trying to index into a variable or call a function and access its results without it being intermediately stored.  See the duplicate for more details.  P.S... it *is* possible, but it's very ugly.  Just use intermediate variables.

Answer (score 0):

Such nested function calls are not allowed in matlab, you have to use a helper function to solve this.

```
paren = @(x, varargin) x(varargin{:});
f2=@(k,x)paren(f(k),x)
f2(3,100)
```